# Fine Uploader Direct to S3 fails in IE8 and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, fine-uploader

I have Fine Uploader 5.0.7 direct to s3 working perfectly in all browsers EXCEPT IE8 and IE9.  I believe I have the plugin initiating settings set up correctly:
cors: {
  allowXdr: true,
  expected: true,
  SendCredentials : true,
  allowCors: true
},

but referencing this blog: http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/, under Handling iframe CORS upload requests server-side I don't understand where I add this:

Your response for iframe based request (such as required when using IE8 or IE9), will look very similar to your normal response, except it must have a Content-Type header value of “text/html”, and your response must import a helper javascript file via a &ltscript&gt tag immediately preceding your valid JSON response. For example:
"{\"success\": true, \"uuid\": \"9da17ad5-ad6a-40cd-81b5-226e837db45b\"}

because I think that is the piece I am missing.

With my current settings IE says:

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Parsing template

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Template parsing complete

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Rendering template in DOM.

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Template rendering complete

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Received 1 files or inputs.

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Sending simple upload request for 0

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Submitting S3 signature request for 0

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Sending POST request for 0

SEC7120: Origin *my domain* not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] POST request for 0 has failed

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Received an empty or invalid response from the server!

[Fine Uploader 5.0.7] Policy signing failed.  Received an empty or invalid response from the server!

Thank you so much for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like an S3 or upload request issue. The signature request is failing.

The logs suggest that your signature server is cross origin and you simply are not returning the proper CORS headers from your server. You'll need to examine the response from your server and ensure the appropriate headers, such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin, are included in the response.

Comment: Thank you Ray for your replay.  If I follow you, this code: signature: {endpoint: "UploadToS3.cfc?method=GetSigET"}  needs to return more then cfcontent type="application/json">{"signature": "#bas64sig#"} ?

Comment: So I have also looked at http://fineuploader.com/demos and the sig functions appear to return the same thing I'm returning: function signRequest() {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
....
    $headersStr = $contentAsObject["headers"];
    if ($headersStr) {
        $response = array('signature' => sign($headersStr));
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {...

Comment: If your signature server resides on a different origin than the page making the request, your server must return proper CORS headers, otherwise the request will fail.

Comment: Everything is on the same server.

Comment: Also I'd love to examine the response I get but not sure how to do that in IE8..looking at the response in FF firebug it looks like those headers present.  Like I said this works BEAUTIFULLY in everything but IE8 and I know it can work because the demo works.  I just haven't been able to nail down what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just more FYI: here is what firebug is telling me:

Comment: [Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Received 1 files.
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)
[Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Attempting to validate image.
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)
[Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Generating new thumbnail for 0
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)
[Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Attempting to draw client-side image preview.
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)

Comment: [Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Not previewable
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)
[Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Sending simple upload request for 0
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)
POST https://dev.me.org/UploadToS3.cfc?method=CreateKey 200 OK 76ms 
jquery-....min.js (line 6)
[Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Submitting S3 signature request for 0
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)
[Fine Uploader 5.2.2] Sending POST request for 0
s3.jque....min.js (line 16)
POST https://dev.me.org/UploadToS3.cfc?method=GetSig 200 OK 63ms

Comment: Sorry, there is very clearly a cross-origin issue here between the page hosting the uploader and the signature server. The browser is indicating this fact. If you are not expecting this, then you'll need to take a closer look at your HTTP traffic or signature endpoint vs the page hosting the uploader to be sure everything is as expected.

Comment: Hi Ray! So the page hosting the uploader and the signature I promise are on the same server but because, if read things correctly, the requests are coming from an iframe for IE8 and 9 fineuploader requests, which in turn makes the server THINK it's from a totally separate server.  So a server setting was changed BUT now our uploader is behind a login, so we have session data, that is not retained when within the iframe call, which then prompts our application to redirect to login.  Is there someway I can get the fineuploader to retain session login with in the iframe?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow. The fact that the request is coming from an iframe should be completely transparent to your server. It will make a request to the same endpoint as the non-iframe upload code (modern browsers), so the exact same endpoint will be hit on the same server in all cases. Also, the issue here is not related to uploads. According to the logs in your question, the issue is related to the POST request sent to your signature endpoint. That request is never sent using an iframe form submit.